# Running the Unit test cases in solr using ant

Tags: unit-testing, ant, solr

I am trying to run my test cases in solr using ant. Below is the ant command I am using:

```
ant test –Dtestcase=<test case name> test  -Dtests.leaveTemporary=true
```

Now I have my own customized solrconfig & schema, so running above command builds the project again & overrites my customized solrconfig & schema.

Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method:
`initCore(String config, String schema, String solrHome)` of class `SolrTestCaseJ4.java` in your `TestCase` and pass the path of your customized schema and config as your solrHome(typical format: `solr\collection1\conf`).

Comment: Thanks , it worked for me . Now i can specify the path to pick solrconfig & schema from .